# Angular app - Material design

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to add material design to an angular app without any luck.

I installed material design, added all the modules to the `app.moduel.ts` file but the components look very bad.

I get this message: `Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide:` https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

I added the link to the head of the index.html file

`<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">`

but for some reason I get a `Status Code:404 Not Found`. I tried to add the css files to assets, which didn't work.

It's a little weird, because if you check the sample app for material design on github there is no link to any theme css file.

https://github.com/jelbourn/material2-app/blob/master/src/index.html

http://localhost:4200/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css

My index.html file looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>M2App</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really depend on how you're structuring and setup your app, but related to `Status Code:404 Not Found` error I think it's because relative path from index.html to `"node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"`cannot be found, and appending some `../../` would help.

Reference to theming guide documentation:

> Alternatively, you can just reference the file directly. This would look something like:
>
> `<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">`
>
> The **actual path** will depend on your server setup.